# jQuery post and redirect php

Tags: php, ajax, json, redirect, post

I have a form with a products table. Initially the table is empty and new products are dynamically inserted with a button press. When user presses the submit button, I would redirect him to a "preview.php" page. But first I need to build a custom JSON object in a function, make a POST request with this object and then redirect to "preview.php". Is that possible ? And what is the better way to perform this ?

Here's a sample of my files :

```
//------------
//invoice.php
//------------

<form id="newInvoice" action="preview.php">
    <table>...</table>
    <button type="submit">Preview</button>
</form>

//-----------
//invoice.js
//-----------

$('#newInvoice').submit(function() {

    var data = [
        "invoicenumber": code,
        "client": {"firstname":"", "lastname":"", ...},
        "products": [{...}, {...}, {...}], //multiple products
        //building the rest of my data here
    ];

    // I don't know what to do here.
    // A call to $.post would send my data asynchronously but I want
    // to send the data as I would do from invoice.php and be redirected 
    // to preview.php.
});

//------------
//preview.php
//------------
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']); // is this correct ?
//...
```

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Unless you're doing some very specific transformations of the form data in javascript, why use JS at all? simply submit the form as you would have WITHOUT javascript?

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want 2 possible submits from the same form? One to preview.php and one to invoice.php?

Comment: Why do you want to `POST` the data as a `JSON` object, when ultimately you want the `$_POST` data?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to POST the data as a JSON object, when ultimately you want the $_POST data?

But if you're keen to do that, you can do so, using `AJAX`. This is used only when you want to return to the client-side code, after executing some PHP(server-side) code.

Comment: Actually I need to send data which is not in the "invoice.php". These data are built on js side after the page is loaded. Is there a way to add more data before making the post request ?

Comment: What do you mean by `Actually I need to send data which is not in the "invoice.php"`? Isn't the data (JSON or POST) formed in `invoice.php`?

Comment: In my "invoice.php", my products table contains only one row as default in which there is a <select name="code">...</select>. User can add other rows dynamically. Since I need to have a unique name for my data when posting from "invoice.php", how can I process these selects when I have more than one product in my data ?

Comment: This is why I thought I should build a custom json data and then post it to "preview.php" as mentionned in my sample above.

Comment: You can process the `selects` by dynamically adding names (when the user adds rows). After that, when you `POST` the invoice.php page, you can access it by the usual $_POST array.

Comment: You just need to have the `form` POST to `preview.php`. `<form action="preview.php" method="post">`